# Remove only the first unnecessary letter from a string

Tags: javascript, string, function, for-loop

for learning purposes I want to remove only the FIRST letter 'a' from a string using a function. My function however removes ALL letters 'a' from the given string.

```
function removeFirstLetterA(str) {
  let letterA = 'a';
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] === letterA) {
      str = str.replace(letterA, '');
    } 
}

return str;
}
```

Can anyone see my mistake and give any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is that you don't stop when you come across and delete the first letter. Inside the if-block, you can `break` the loop, so that it won't continue after deleting the first one.

```
...
if (str[i] === letterA) {
  str = str.replace(letterA, '');
  break;
} 
...
```

Btw, you don't need a loop to delete the first match. Replace already does that. This would be enough:

```
function removeFirstLetterA(str) {
    return str.replace('a', '');
}
```